# Laravel I cannot pull a single row that is not contained in Query result

Tags: laravel, postgresql, orm

First I apologize for my bad english.

I want to get first `category=1` posts and then, only one post not equal Posts.The code I wrote is below, is there wrong in my code, or I am sending an incorrect query because I use `postgreSql`.

```
$posts= Post::where('category',1)->get();

$onlyone = Post::where('id','!=', $posts)->first();
```

Comment: actually your requirement is not clear. It's clear that first you want to get posts that category equals to 1, and then what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should get you what you want...

```
$posts = Post::where('category', 1)->get();
$onlyone= Post::where('category', '!=', 1)->first();
```

If you actually have a collection of posts that you want to exclude you want to do something like `Post::whereNotIn('id', $posts->pluck('id'))->first();`

Comment: Thank you very much, worked like a charm.("pluck" is what I need)